# how to write Elastic search query for exact match for a string

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I am using kibanna
I am trying to put filter on a field container_name = "**armenian**"
but I have other container names with following names

1. armenian_alpha
2. armenian_beta
3. armenian_gama
4. armenian1
5. armenian2

after putting the filter , search query in kibanna becomes

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "container_name": {
        "query": "armenian",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the output searches logs for all containers , as I can see the Elastic search query is using a pattern matching

How can I put an exact match with the string provided and avoid the rest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out with `term` query. Do note that it is case sensitive by default unless you specify with `case_insensitive` equals to `true`. Also, if your `container_name` is a `text` field type instead of `keyword` field type, do add the `.keyword` after the field name. Otherwise, ignore the `.keyword`.

Example:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "container_name.keyword": {
        "value": "armenian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Link here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a direct wildcard in `query` or `wildcard` as follow

```bash
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "container_name": {
        "query": "*armenian",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "container_name": {
        "value": "*armenian"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With `*armenian` you are ensuring that `armenian` comes at the end.